# How to make the latest date in front line on the chart x-row in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I try to make the chart in powerbi showing lateset date is in first row like this.

date  2023-08-11   2023-08-10    2023-08-09

What I found is using RANK DAX. --> rankx (all('tablename'),[Date],,DESC,dense)

but the result using above DAX shows the number like this -445645 which may be changed from the date. so when sorting by column with above dax row.
it seems it's not showing the date.

Could you let me know how to show the date as above in neat?

Comment: Can you please provide more information ?

Comment: sure, I mean, If I make a table, then usually date shows 2023-8-12 2023-08-13 2023-08-14 in order.  but what I want to make is to show it 2023  08-14  2023-08-13 2023-08-12...  latest date to show in front using DAX.